# show line error code in javascript

Tags: javascript

im beginner in JavaScript and im building simple JavaScript module

```
var sky = (function () {
    var defaults = {}
    var validate = {
        argNum: function (arg, num) {
            if (arg != num) {
                throw new Error('illegal argument count');
            };
        }
    }
    return {
        event: function (elementName, eventName, functionName) {
            validate.argNum(arguments.length, 3);
            if (elementName.addEventListener) {
                elementName.addEventListener(eventName, functionName, false);
            } else {
                elementName.attachEvent("on" + eventName, functionName);
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

and when i call it like that

```
sky.event("",document,"DOMContentLoaded",function() {
    console.log("dom loaded");
});
```

in error console the error line is

[image]

i want show error message in the called function that have 4 arguments not 3 ?

Comment: You might want to look into [`function.arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Comment: I read this about 10 times and can realize what problem you got. Your error is thrown as it should be.

Comment: why not the error in this line 
sky.event("",document,"DOMContentLoaded",function() {
    console.log("dom loaded");
});

Comment: Oh, now I got it. This is how `throw` behaves. It shows itself, since the exception was thrown from this line, not from actual function call. Basicly the function call isn't erranous.

Comment: @SkyWalker damn.. now its clear! You write everything in your post but not that *you want the error thrown in the call line*... It's impossible, the `throw` command stops in his line, not what you wants.. How do you want to compiler guess what line is **your** error? There's no magic that can do it, dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are passing extra argument `""` for `event` method

```
sky.event("",document,"DOMContentLoaded", function(){
----------^
```

But it should be like this, as your method `event` definition expects three parameter than four

```
sky.event(document,"DOMContentLoaded", function(){
```

Comment: i know i want the error appear in the line 
sky.event("",document,"DOMContentLoaded",function() { console.log("dom loaded"); }); – Sky Walker
i mean in the console instad of the line in the pic